# Extract arguments from MeshRegion created by STL import

Tags: import, mesh

I've been trying to extract points and polygons from a MeshRegion expression created by importing an STL file. At first I thought I could use a simple ReplaceAll as shown below:

```
test = Abc[{a1, b2},  Method -> {method}];
test /. Abc[a_, b_] :> a
```

This worked. However, the following does not:

```
test2 = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1,
 2}}, Pyramid[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], Boxed -> True];

test2 /. MeshRegion[a_, b_] :> a
```

I get the error message

```
MeshRegion::bdcoord: The coordinates given at position 1 in MeshRegion[a_,b_] are not a list of real-valued points in the same dimension. >>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look up `MeshCoordinates`.

Comment: `MeshRegion` is atomic: `AtomQ[test2]` returns `True`.

Comment: Also, to avoid the message use `HoldPattern[MeshRegion][a_, b_] :> a`. Your replacement rule is trying to evaluate before being applied.

Comment: @ChipHurst you are right it is atomic. But why does that stop me extracting the argument? If you test Sin there is no problem:


test = Sin[{1, 2, 3}];
test /. Sin[a_] :> a 
Out[36]= {1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 3):

You can import vertex coordinates and polygons directly from your stl file:

```
Import["ExampleData/spikey.stl", #] & /@ {"VertexData", "PolygonData"}
```

You can also extract vertex positions and polygons from the `MeshRegion` using the functions `MeshCoordinates` and `MeshCells`

Comment: It would be more efficient to do a single import using `Import["ExampleData/spikey.stl", {{"VertexData", "PolygonData"}}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks, the double brackets are not obvious in the help!